Google Analytics: 'You do not have permission to access this account' error despite having proper permissions
When I try to log into my Goolge Analytics,
You do not have permission to access the account, property, or view in question. Please contact your analytics administrator who has user management privileges.”
error, and I am unable to access my Google Analytics.
[Background]
First, I created the property in the wrong account and put it in the trash.
After that, when I access Analytics, I am forcefully redirected to the deleted property that I put in the recycle bin, and I am getting the error message above.
I have tried the following methods.
Delete the browser cache.
Switching to a different browser
Switch to another Google account.
Restart your PC.
Stop all add-ons of the browser.
Browser restart
Restart the modem
I asked ChatGPT for countermeasures and tried up↑ but no improvement.
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.
Please help.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
I have tried the following methods.
Delete the browser cache.
Switching to a different browser
Switch to another Google account.
Restart your PC.
Stop all add-ons of the browser.
Browser restart
Restart the modem
I was hoping that by trying ↑ I would be able to successfully access my Goolge Analytics account.

Try admin link:
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/?pagename=admin
